# Get rid of all white spaces in between lines

Tags: python

So say i had some text like this:

```
line num 1
line num 2

line num 3



line num 4
```

I am trying to get rid of all the new lines in  between line 2 and 3 and line 3 and 4 while having all of the line num on separate new lines. How would i accomplish this? I have already tried puth=ing them into a list then looping throught them and taking out all of the lone '\n'

ex:

```
obj=['line num 1','line num 2','\n','line num 3','\n','\n','line num4']
a=-1
for i in obj:
    a+=1
    if i=='\n':
        print 'yes'
        del obj[a]


print obj
```

output:

```
['line num 1', 'line num 2', 'line num 3', '\n', 'line num4']
```

It catches some but not all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: don't erase elements while iterating over a list.

Here you will find lot of ways to do this: [Remove items from a list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python)

Note: this is probably the shortest and most pythonic:

```
filter(lambda x: x!='\n', obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply use regex on the whole file content:

```
>>> s = """line num 1
line num 2

line num 3



line num 4"""
>>> import re
>>> print re.sub('\n+', '\n', s)
line num 1
line num 2
line num 3
line num 4
```

P.S. You should newer change list while iterating it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `if not item.isspace()` gives you something more readable:

```
>>> obj = ['line num 1', 'line num 2', '\n', 'line num 3', '\n', '\n', 'line num4']

>>> [item for item in obj if not item.isspace()]

['line num 1', 'line num 2', 'line num 3', 'line num4']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_new_line(obj):
    if "\n" in obj:
        obj.remove("\n")
    remove_new_line(obj)
    return obj

obj = ['line num 1', 'line num 2', '\n', 'line num 3', '\n', '\n', 'line num4']

print remove_new_line(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
f = open("your file.txt",'r')
values = f.read()
val = re.split(r"\n+",values)
print val
```

output = `['line num 1', 'line num 2', 'line num 3', 'line num 4']`